# What is the font used by http://tex.stackexchange.com/?

Tags: discussion, fonts

I am curious to know the font used to display `http://tex.stackexchange.com/`'s webpages because I want to use is to write my LaTeX articles.

To be more precise, I am interested in the font used to display my current question.

Comment: I mean the font used to display my question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Header: Palatino Linotype

Text: Lucida Grande

Code text: Consolas

At least that's what computed CSS says (accessible in FF via `Right Click -> Inspect Element -> Right Bottom Panel -> Computed -> font-family`).

However: 
**Do not use web fonts for printed articles.
 
Do not use web fonts for printed articles.
 
Do not use web fonts for printed articles.**

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I succeeded to run it by calling this: `\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Lucida Grande}`

Comment: Why not to use web fonts for printed articles ?

Comment: @begueradj They are not ment to be used as such. They will not perform as they do on screen. The creation of type faces is an art and the creator uses certain tricks to get it beautiful on screen or on paper.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thank you for the answer.

Comment: Text: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, Tahoma, or any sans-serif font. Title: Palatino Linotype, Palatino, Hoefler Text, Book Antiqua, Georgia, or any serif font. Code:  Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, or any monospace font, or any serif font.

Comment: In general, yes, definitely web and print fonts are separate. But shouldn't Palatino work well in print?

Comment: I'd really like to add: **Do not use web fonts for printed articles.**

Comment: Do these count as web fonts?  I know of journals and books published in Lucida Grande.  Palatino as well has been around for a long time before it was used on the web.

Comment: Maybe someone could provide the closest print-use analogs?

Comment: Normally, for print you should use sans-serif fonts mainly for headers and short texts. Longer texts should be printed with a serif font because of better legibility. On screen, usually fonts with larger x-heights and often sans-serif fonts are used, since screens have a quite low resolution. But apart from that, Palatino is of course a nice font to use for print. For print, you might choose Myriad as a nice substitute for Lucida, like Apple does it.

Comment: @WChargin Yes, Palatino is fine, but it's used only for the headers. Lucida Grande is IMHO a bad choice for a print font. Just try to zoom in the page and read it from significantly further distance: suddenly the clean and round shape of the font makes it difficult to read it. That's because LG is a good screen font, but not a good print font. In general, I like the Lucida family, but only on the screen.